# How to use Invoke-WebRequest to see the sent headers?

Tags: powershell, webrequest

When I'm using the following command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://example.com -SessionVariable Foo -UserAgent Bar
```

I get the following output:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!doctype html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Example Domain</title>

                        <meta charset="utf-8" />
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; 
                    charset=utf-8" />
                        <meta name="viewport" conten...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Vary: Accept-Encoding
                    X-Cache: HIT
                    Content-Length: 1270
                    Cache-Control: max-age=604800
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 16:38:28 GMT
                    Expires: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 16:38...
Forms             : 
Headers           : {[Vary, Accept-Encoding], [X-Cache, HIT], [Content-Length, 
                    1270], [Cache-Control, max-age=604800]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {@{outerHTML=<a 
                    href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More 
                    information...</a>; tagName=A; 
                    href=http://www.iana.org/domains/example}}
ParsedHtml        : 
RawContentLength  : 1270
```

But the problem is, that I cannot see the headers which were sent (either the session variable or the user agent). Maybe it's get truncated by `...`?

How can I display the headers which were sent?

Comment: Try this: `Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://example.com -SessionVariable Foo -UserAgent Bar | Select -ExpandProperty Headers` Let me know if it gets you anywhere.

Comment: @JacobColvin Thank you, expanding works fine, so it's good to know, but I think these are the headers received, not sent, as I still can't find the user agent there.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try expanding RawContent? That should have it, if it's returned at all. I didn't realize, but it is also truncated in the default response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't store the request header AFAIK. If you want specific values in the header then it expects you to specify them with the parameters `-Headers` and `-UserAgent`.

`HttpWebRequest` or `WebRequest` provides more control if you prefer that.

```
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
$res = $req.GetResponse()

$req.Headers.Keys | % { "$_ = $($req.Headers[$_])" }
Host = stackoverflow.com

$req | fl Method, UserAgent, ProtocolVersion
Method          : GET
UserAgent       :
ProtocolVersion : 1.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the HTTP headers using PowerShell:

```
$url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' 
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing # can be used curl instead Invoke-WebRequest
$result.RawContent # outup in raw
$result.Headers # Get the HTTP headers formatted as a table.
$result.Headers.Date # Get a specific item from the HTTP header.
```

[Source](https://techexpert.tips/powershell/powershell-get-http-headers/)

Comment: This shows the headers that were in the received response, not in the sent request.

Comment: bad eyes. sorry