# How to log requests sent with Powershells Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

When using the PowerShell command `Invoke-WebRequest`, is it somehow possible to write the content of the request into a file?

In Dev Tools of browsers it is possible to log requests, it would be handy when I could that in PowerShell as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Invoke-WebRequest to see the sent headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870540/how-to-use-invoke-webrequest-to-see-the-sent-headers)